# Explicit com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER intent

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I migrated to GCM from C2DM way back when, so I'm still registering by creating a `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER` intent and passing it to `startService`, as specified in the [GCM migration documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html#client) (which apparently is out of date):

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "xxxxxx");
context.startService(registrationIntent);
```

Starting Android 5.0 Intents need to be explicit: how can I do this here? I could call `setComponent` on the intent, but what would I use as the component name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a function that converts `ExplicitFromImplicitIntent`:

```
Intent explicit = createExplicitFromImplicitIntent(mContext, registrationIntent);
startService(explicit);

public static Intent createExplicitFromImplicitIntent(Context context, Intent implicitIntent) {
    // Retrieve all services that can match the given intent
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = pm.queryIntentServices(implicitIntent, 0);
    if (resolveInfo == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Get component info and create ComponentName
    ResolveInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfo.get(0);
    String packageName = serviceInfo.serviceInfo.packageName;
    String className = serviceInfo.serviceInfo.name;
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(packageName, className);

    // Create a new intent. Use the old one for extras and such reuse
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(implicitIntent);

    // Set the component to be explicit
    explicitIntent.setComponent(component);

    return explicitIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply stop using that intent, which is long deprecated. Since mid 2013, the recommended way to register to GCM is via the `Google Play Services` library, and all it requires is calling a single `register` method of the `GoogleCloudMessaging` class.

Example (taken from the [official demo](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java)):

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
...

/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Note that the registration is done in the background (via an `AsyncTask`) since the new registration method is blocking, so it can't be called on the main thread.

Comment: If there's a simple way to keep using the old way (and no consequences visible to the end user), I'd rather not re-write my entire registration logic, you know?

Comment: @MohamedHafez You can continue using the same old code, which is deprecated, and hope that it still works.